# iOS virtual keyboard in Safari: Change "Go" to "Enter"

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari

I know that if you have the keyword "search" on

```
<input type="search">
```

Safari on iOS recognizes this and shows "Search" instead of "Go" in the virtual keyboard. Are there any other keywords that are recognized? I would like to name it "Enter" because on a tag-input, neither "Search" nor "Go" makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As for today, there's no room for customization of the return key text.

There's a [fixed list](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html) of input types that Safari mobile recognizes, but you cannot do anything more than setting of one them and let Safari choose the proper keyboard appearance.

Comment: thanks Gabriele, not what I hoped for but a perfect answer and useful reference!

Comment: How about getting Next button instead of Go when you are in the middle of the form? This works in native apps, but is there a way of getting similar functionality on web forms?